# Linux file system - command to allocate file system blocks inside kernel for inode

Tags: c, linux, kernel

What are the typical commands linux uses internally inside the kernel to get pointers to the data blocks on the file system (which are stored inside inodes)?

Comment: Mapping an offset from the start of data for an inode to a physical block is very filesystem specific, and some filesystems optimize the storage to avoid allocating whole blocks for small files. Several filesystem drivers make use of the `mpage` functions declared in <linux/mpage.h> to read and write individual pages or lists of pages, using a callback function of type `get_block_t` (declared in <linux/fs.h>) to map offsets to blocks.